# При повторном открытии Activity нажав в уведомлении переменная stream оказывается пустой

Tags: android

При повторном открытии Activity нажав в уведомлении переменная stream оказывается пустой. Как это можно исправить?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView list;

    private final String RADIO = "ссылка на радио";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        String[] radios = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.kavkazradios);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, radios);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                CharSequence strCharSequence = ((TextView) view).getText();
                String str = strCharSequence.toString().trim();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class);

                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("Радио")) {
                    intent.putExtra("stream", RADIO);
                    intent.putExtra("radio", str);
                    intent.putExtra("rec", 1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifManager.cancelAll();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

PlayerActivity

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String stream;
    private String radio;
    private int rec;
    private boolean isPlay;
    private String MAYBE_ACTION = "MAYBE_ACTION";

    private ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private TextView txtRadio;
    private TextView txtMusic;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    TrackSelector trackSelector;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";

    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;

    BroadcastReceiver br;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);
        txtMusic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMusic);

        stream = getIntent().getExtras().getString("stream").toString().trim();
        radio = getIntent().getExtras().getString("radio").toString().trim();
        rec = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("rec");
        setTitle(radio);

        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory streamSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(streamSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl());
        simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        //Set media controller
        simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
        // Bind the player to the view.
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(stream);
        // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
        // Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.

        if (stream.contains("m3u8")) {
            MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
            // Prepare the player with the source.
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
        } else {
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
        }

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        isPlay = true;

        if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
            btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
        }

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Intent closeIntent = new Intent();
        closeIntent.setAction(MAYBE_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setTicker(radio)
                .setContentTitle("Играет: " + radio)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pendingIntent)
                .build();

        builder.flags = builder.flags | Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder);

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            // действия при получении сообщений
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                finish();
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);

        txtRadio.setText("Сейчас играет: " + radio);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver NetworkChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
            Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifManager.cancelAll();
        super.onDestroy();
        player.release();
        if (NetworkChangeReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }

    public void onPlayPause(View view) {
        if (isPlay == true) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == true) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                isPlay = false;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
            }
        } else if (isPlay == false) {
            if (player.getPlayWhenReady() == false) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                isPlay = true;
                btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_stop);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Вот что в маркете

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.sergey89.radios/ru.sergey89.radios.Player}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at ru.sergey89.radios.Player.onCreate(Player.java:118)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, код, которым вы формируете PendingIntent.

Comment: В вопрос добавил оба кода Activity. Полные версии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не добавляете в intent ни одной extra:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Поэтому вот этот getExtras() в onCreate() закономерно возвращает null со всеми вытекающими:

```
stream = getIntent().getExtras().getString("stream").toString().trim();
```

Comment: у меня в коде так и записано вроде

Comment: Да, это ваш код. Первая строчка - это intent, который будет запускать активити. Вторая - упаковка этого intent внутрь pending intent для передачи с нотификацией. Проблема в том, что интент, созданный в первой строчке, *не содержит* ни одной extra. А активити их ждет и даже не проверяет их наличие, поэтому падает.

Comment: Аа понял что нужно написать что-то типа этого после первой строчки

        intent.putExtra("stream", stream);
        intent.putExtra("radio", radio);
        intent.putExtra("rec", rec);

Comment: а почему такое происходило не всегда? иной раз тыкаешь в уведомление нормально запускается Player, а иногда крах

Comment: Вероятно потому, что не падает оно, когда эта активити уже запущена (тем другим интентом, который с extra), а по нотификации приложение только становится видимым.

Comment: Т.е. когда из MainActivity перешли в Player intent знает о переменной stream. А когда из уведомления перешли, то уже не знает и падает?

Comment: Вы должны понять, что открывается новая активити. Она никак со старой не взаимодействует. И интент который ее открывает у вас другой

Comment: понял. Буду знать теперь.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны в `intent` положить переменную `stream`, т.к. активити эта откроется уже с помощью этого интента.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
intent.putExtra("stream", stream);
```

Comment: У меня так и есть. Но иногда когда из уведомления открываю активность Player то приложение крашится. Приложение уже выложено в маркет и там показал 2 сбоя даже есть эксепшн. ЩАс в свой вопрос вставлю